# VS2012 does not show some functions from DLL reference

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I ran into an odd issue today in which a Visual Studio does not show some of the functions from an DLL referenced in a C# project.

Specifically, I have a C# project referencing a DLL `SASInterop.DLL` which, among other things, contains a the interface `ILibref`, and I knew this interface should have a function named something along the lines of `ListMembers`. However, Intellisense had no knowledge of such a function and when pointing the Object Browser at the reference it agrees with Intellisense; no such function exists.

But after much experimenting and poking I opened the DLL in IL DASM and sure enough, there is a function named `ListDataSets` along with a pair of other functions that Visual Studio does not show. Using this function in code works perfectly, and the mouseover tooltip even displays the correct signature.

Looking at the various functions in IL DASM I can see nothing that distinguishes the functions recognized by Intellisense from those that are not. Can anyone shed any light on this? I am not very well versed in the subject of DLLs and my google-fu is failing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason [EditorBrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx/css) which will hide item from intellisense.

Comment: This would appear to be the case. Looking at the assembly again the functions have `TypeLibFuncAttribute` values that I assume flag them as hidden. Thank you.